# Is GL_R8 and GL_R8UI different in OpenGL?

Tags: python, c++, opengl

I created a module, [ModernGL](https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/ModernGL) to simplify the use of OpenGL in python3.

This is how I choose the proper format for a renderbuffer with 1, 2, 3 or 4 components:

```
const int int_formats[] = {0, GL_R8, GL_RG8, GL_RGB8, GL_RGBA8};
const int float_formats[] = {0, GL_R32F, GL_RG32F, GL_RGB32F, GL_RGBA32F};

int format = floats ? float_formats[components] : int_formats[components];

...

gl.RenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, format, width, height);
```

For example a renderbuffer with `components=1` and `floats=False` will choose the `format=GL_R8`

Previusly (before this [commit](https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/ModernGL/commit/90063b1c1e553de48748788b1a68c26d6b2a5fa4)) I had:

```
const int int_formats[] = {0, GL_R8UI, GL_RG8UI, GL_RGB8UI, GL_RGBA8UI};
```

> According to [this documentation](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Format):
>    If you want a 3-component unsigned integral format, with 8 bits per component, you use GL_RGB8UI. A 1-component floating-point format that uses 16-bits per component is GL_R16F.

**However**

When I choose `GL_R8UI` the glReadPixels() will fail with `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`
When I choose `GL_R8` the glReadPixels() will read the pixels as `unsigned chars`

I have a [test](https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/ModernGL/blob/master/tests/test_framebuffer.py) that fails with the non supported format.

- What is the difference between `GL_R8` and `GL_R8UI`
- Why am I able to create a Renderbuffer with `GL_R8UI`, but reading fails.

**Note:** I tested with `GL_R8UI`, `GL_RGB8UI` and `GL_RGBA8UI` none of them were working when `glReadPixels` was called.

Comment: the snippet is from [this file](https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/ModernGL/blob/master/src/Context.cpp#L1171)

Comment: You cannot use [`ReadPixels`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLAPI/glReadPixels) with a *sized* format - if your color buffer has an internal format of `R8UI`, the you need to read from it using the appropriate *integer* format - which in your case needs to be `RG_INTEGER` with type `UNSIGNED_BYTE`. `ReadPixels` will then pack the values as you expect.

Comment: Thank you @thokra, I was looking for a solution for days.

Comment: Don't beat yourself up, you have to read the spec carefully to find this - the official man page doesn't state anything pertaining to non-normalized formats, which I consider a bug. In terms of the spec, check table **8.3** and look for mentions of `ReadPixels` across various chapters (I refer to the core GL 4.5 spec).

Comment: BTW, I you have trouble memorizing combinations of formats, internal format and type and what not, you can always abstract all of this away into a structure that maps a format you specify to the corresponding arguments used by the GL. The Unreal engine does that as well, for instance. It also really helps getting platform dependent GL/GLES renderer implementations under control (because they use different formats to express the same thing, most notably perhaps `RGBA`/`RBGA16F`/`FLOAT` in GL vs. `RGBA`/`RGBA`/`HALF_FLOAT` in extended GLES2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A long time ago, OpenGL functions worked the way your simplified API does. They accepted 1, 2, 3, or 4 as a "number of components" and chose the correct format.  This has long since been abandoned, because there are not only too many different formats we want to support, but we also want to be able to interpret those formats in different ways.

Consider the data type `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`.

- We can normalize it, converting it to a floating-point number in the range 0..1 with 8 bits of precision.  Internal format `GL_R8`, with `uniform sampler2D`, which produces `vec4`.
- We can decide not to normalize it.  Same as above, only now the values are in the range 0..255.
- We can treat it as an integer in the range 0..255.  Internal format `GL_R8UI`, with `uniform usampler2D`, which produces `uvec4`.

The same is true for renderbuffers.  If your fragment shader starts with this:

```
out float Color;
```

Then you can render to `GL_R8`.

However, if your fragment shader starts with this:

```
out uint Color;
```

Then you have to render to a different format, like `GL_R8UI`.  Note that the rules for integers are somewhat restrictive in OpenGL: you can't use filtering with integer textures, and you can't use alpha blending with fragment output (you can use `ADD`, `SUBTRACT`, `MIN`, or `MAX` though).

So in short, `GL_R8` and `GL_R8UI` are both compatible with `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, but they work completely differently when you use them in a program. That's why the OpenGL functions don't just take a number of components as a parameter any more.

Comment: Can you read from a framebuffer with a color attachment that has a fromat of `GL_R8UI`? I get invalid operation but my case is none of [these](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glReadPixels.xhtml#errors).

Comment: As I understood `GL_R8UI` and `GL_R8` expects different output type from the fragment shader. I post the reading issue as a separate question.